# How to find increasing trend from a python list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby

I want to print the increasing trend that I am getting between **Jan and Mar, Sept to Dec.** for the below provided data
Can you please help me with the logic, please.

I have tried the following code but its just not right:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
month=['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec']

count=[100,200,300,100,120,100,90,80,90,100,110,120]
dicta={'month':month,'count':count}
input_data=pd.DataFrame(dicta)
print(input_data)
flag=0
counter=[]

indexer=[]
for index in range(len(input_data['count'].values)-1):

print('The index is',index)
a=input_data.iloc[index,0]
b=input_data.iloc[index+1,0]
if b>a:
    flag=flag+1
    print('if loop flag:',flag)
elif flag<2:
    flag=0
    print('elif loop flag')
else:
    counter.append(flag)
    print('else flag',counter)
    flag=0
print(flag)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily need all those imports for this.

```
trendList = []
trendStart = 0
trendEnd = 0
valuePrev = 0

count = 0
for value in count:
   count += 1
   if count == 1:
       valuePrev = value
       trendStart = count
   elif valuePrev <= value:     #extend if equal or greater
       trendEnd = count
       valuePrev = value
   else:                        #end trend if current is less
       trendEnd = count - 1
       trendList.append([trendStart,trendEnd])
       trendStart = count
       valuePrev = value
for trend in trendList:
    print str(trend[0]) + " to " + str(trend[1])
```

*note* this is looking STRICTLY at the values, not including months

Comment: You can also trim the trendList by:  if trendStart != trendEnd and trendEnd - trendStart > 1: trendList.append([trendStart, trendEnd])

Comment: Thanks for the code. But it identifies only the first trend. Somehow the second trend is not coming properly. Output i got is this:
1to3
4to4
5to5
6to6
7to7
8to8
9to9
10to10
11to11..it should be 8 to 11.

Comment: The code worked out fine once I added trendList.append([trendStart,trendEnd]) at the end of the first for loop.